# How do i destroy only 1 object when 2 instances of the same object collide?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry im at work and don't have access to my code but basically. If i set it to destroy the "other" since nothing is destroyed until the end of the update both objects get flagged for destruction. I don't care which one survives for right now just trying to understand the idea of how to do this. In the future i might create a new instance where the 2 hit but again then both would trigger the creation of a new instance and the 2 new instances would collide ect ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can make a flag that tells you if you've been destroyed. If so, you can't destroy anyone else. Then, whichever 'collide' method gets called first will be the survivor. It would be something like this:

```
private bool alreadyDead = false;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (!alreadyDead) {
        MyScript script = collision.gameobject.GetComponent<MyScript>();
        if (script != null) {
             script.alreadyDead = true;
             collision.gameobject.Destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad basically the answer i got on unity also. Was really hoping something like what Chris showed would have worked, it just seems cleaner lol

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set a flag of some sort to check against. You could set a boolean on a script, or maybe even toggle the active state of the GameObject you want to destroy, and in turn not have the disabled GameObject go through with its collision/destroying method.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {
    // Only proceed if this gameObject is active
    if (gameObject.activeSelf) {
        // Disable the other gameObject we've collided with, then flag to destroy it
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that works i think that makes more sense than setting a flag since this way the other collision will not even be called. I'm new to unity i knew it didn't issue the destroy command until the end of the cycle wasn't sure about setactive or other properties.

Comment: I tried this and it does work (or at least now it does).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After quite a bit of digging, I come up with this solution:

I have two eggs spawning on a int grid, if they overlap while spawning, the one with a higher instance id will get destroyed.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{  

    if (other.CompareTag(Tags.Egg))
    { 
        if (this.GetInstanceID() > other.GetInstanceID())
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way of doing this is to check for overlap at the Start() in class Egg.
But the code I wrote doesn't seem to do the job.

```
private void Start()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(gameObject.transform.position, transform.localScale / 2, Quaternion.identity, default);

    //Check when there is an existing collider at the spot coming into contact with the new spawn egg
    if ( hitColliders.Length != 0)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

The second method failed that for some reason it just keep destroying all the spawn Eggs.